# Using Facebook Connect with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, authlogic, facebooker

I am trying to make Authlogic and Facebook Connect (using Facebook) play nice so that you can create an account either the normal registration way or with Facebook connect. I have been able to get the connect to work one way but logging out only loggs out on facebook and not on my site, I have to delete the cookies to make it working. Any help would be awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example app I made using the Facebook Connect extension, authlogic and Open ID.  It still needs some work, but it does function.

http://big-glow-mama.heroku.com/

http://github.com/holden/authlogic_openid_selector_example/tree/with-facebook/

Comment: Great work!  This helped me out when adding facebook connect to my example site.  

This example has all the basic site goodies.
http://github.com/jspooner/authlogic_cucumber_rspec_example

Answer (score 3):

This is a good gem for that.
http://github.com/viatropos/authlogic-connect

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Facebook Connect extension](http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect) for AuthLogic?

Comment: yeah but it didnt seem to work... oh well i will just use restful_authentication. thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

just tried omniauth with authlogic, that works like a charm
btw, authlogic-connect is out-dated

You also have an example app to check (Authlogic + Omniauth)
http://omniauth-authlogic-demo.heroku.com/